# Splitting polygon based on number of points in it using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, splitting, polygon-creation, point-in-polygon

Based on the mock-up below, is it possible to split a polygon into multiple polygons depending on the number of points that are within that polygon?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1.

[image: Example]

I know there is a caveat how would you know in which direction would you split the polygon? But let's just say I want to split the polygon vertically not horizontally.

Comment: [Thiessen Tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/create-thiessen-polygons.htm)

Comment: @Hornbydd damn you are awesome :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A software independent algorithmic approach that you can implement with whatever geospatial software:

1. Create Voronoi (Thiessen) Polygons from the points with a margin large enough to cover the whole polygon.
2. Create the intersection of these voronoi polygons with the initial polygon.

*Red: intersection of voronoi/thiessen polygons (dotted line) with the initial polygon:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the super quick response. But I have tens of thousands of polygons so naturally I also have thousands of points.  So is there a tool in Pro that can automate step 1?

Comment: As I don't have access to ArcGIS, I can just tell you the principle steps, but most geospatial softwares can create Voronoi/Thiessen polygons automatically, as @Hornbydd added in their comment.